# Azure Service Bus Schedules Messages cancellation using the message content or message header data

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I would like to cancel the scheduled messages in the service bus `queue/topic` using the message content.

e.g: the scheduled message in `queue/topic` will be like this `{UserName:'Scott', Test: 'This is test msg'}`

I would like to cancel the schedules message using the `UserName`

Note: I am not saving the cancellation token, which i can use to cancel the scheduled message.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not possible to cancel a scheduled message based on a user property. Only way you could cancel a scheduled message is by it's `SequenceNumber` property.

Thanks to Sean Feldman for his [`blog post`](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages) on the same topic, here's how you can cancel a scheduled message if you know the message's `SequenceNumber` property:

```
var sequenceNumber = await queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(300)).ConfigureAwait(false);
await queueClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber).ConfigureAwait(false);
```